# Parsing HTML with jsoup into Parquet files on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, jsoup, parquet

I'm just getting started with Parquet, and I'm finding the documentation to be a bit sparse. I have a subscription to Safari Books Online, and I've looked at all the books containing information about Parquet, and even the books I looked at only contained a few paragraphs each. I'm struggling to figure out where to begin here.

*The Problem*

I am parsing 400 million HTML files. Each file represents a person (it's a resume). For each file, a JSON object will be created, containing top level person data (e.g., name, title, location), and a nested structure containing experience, education, and skills. Now, the goal is to have these objects in Parquet files, stored on S3, with Presto, or some distributed SQL query engine on top, for analysis. What I was hoping to do was parse the HTML and put into Parquet files, without JSON as an intermediary. However, I'm not 100% sure how to do this, and I can't find anything to get me started here. I was thinking, parse each HTML file, create the JSON object, and write to the Parquet file. That way I don't have to create a bunch of JSON files, then create Parquet files from them (save myself the step), but not even sure how to write the files stored on S3, or if I am even thinking about all of this correctly.

Just looking for some guidance here on getting started with this. Any good resources on what best practices are here, how to go about it, that sort of thing. I imagine if people are using Parquet (and it seems to be the case), there must be some documentation that I am simply missing.